# Send mail to Myself using Powershell

Tags: powershell

I managed to send mail using powershell, but what i want is for the one who runs the script be the one who send it and receive the mail so it should be automatic. and I don't know how i can manage to do that, So I'm asking for your help please.
here is my code

```
$Outlook = New-Object -ComObject Outlook.Application
$Mail = $Outlook.CreateItem(0)
$Mail.To = #need to be the mail of the one who runs the script
$Mail.Subject = "send mail"
$Mail.Body = "This is my mail"
$Mail.Send()    
Write-Host "Mail Sent Successfully"
```

Comment: Try `$Outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI").Accounts.Item(1).SmtpAddress`

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I forgot to mention that I'm a beginner and where can I apply your line please?

Comment: The only dependency is the `$Outlook` variable, so anywhere after your first line. Try `$Mail.To = $Outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI").Accounts.Item(1).SmtpAddress` for example

Comment: You gave a great idea but when I use it like you said, I keep on getting an error like if I Didn't specify the destination address

Comment: You forgot to also add a `From` address (mandatory)

Comment: I appreciate your answer Theo and I tried sending an email without a `From` and I receives the mail if I set manually the destination address

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding to Mathias comment, this is working for me;

```
$Outlook = New-Object -ComObject Outlook.Application
$Mail = $Outlook.CreateItem(0)
$Mail.Sender = $Outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI").Accounts.Item(1).SmtpAddress # or 'noreply@domain.com'
$Mail.To = $Outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI").Accounts.Item(1).SmtpAddress
$Mail.Subject = "send mail"
$Mail.Body = "This is my mail"
$Mail.Send()
```

This is working without a `Sender` address for me, it uses my default mail profile - but you could try manually specifying that if it's not working for you.

Comment: This is useful but for some reason it doesn't work for me maybe their is some restrictions anyway Thank you  @Elkenyo

Comment: You could also try the Send-MailMessage PowerShell cmdlet instead, if you have access to a mail relay, e.g; `Send-MailMessage -From 'noreply@domain.com' -To $address -SmtpServer 'smtprelay.internal'`

Comment: I used this method first and I had problems with my STMPSERVER  I can't even get It from  Office 365. Well i guess I'm gonna stick to  adding mail address manually in the script. 
Thank you again for your help

Answer (score 0):

Well I managed to find something that worked for me. all I did is put the `$Outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI").Accounts.Item(1).SmtpAddress` in a variable and call it after that

```
$Outlook = New-Object -ComObject Outlook.Application
$Mail = $Outlook.CreateItem(0)
$email  = $Outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI").Accounts.Item(1).SmtpAddress 
$Mail.To = "$email"
$Mail.Subject = "send mail"
$Mail.Body = "This is my mail"
$Mail.Send()
```

Thank you again for your help !